# Adding an Image Input Element in Laravel Blade Template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to upload a image using input tag in laravel Blade Template with the following line ..

```
{{ Form::image('blog/images/search_btn.gif', 'button_search', ['class' => 'button_search']) }}
```

But it continuously showing Error in the view page

> syntax error, unexpected 'content' (T_STRING), expecting ']'

This is my View Page Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>@yield('title')</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
{!!Html::style('blog/style.css')!!}
{!!Html::style('blog/js/cufon-yui.js')!!}
{!!Html::script('blog/js/arial.js')!!}
{!!Html::script('blog/js/cuf_run.js')!!}

</head>
<body>
<div class="main">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header_resize">
      <div class="menu_nav"> 
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
          <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clr"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="searchform">
        <form id="formsearch" name="formsearch" method="post" action="#">

           {{ Form::image('blog/images/search_btn.gif', 'button_search', ['class' => 'button_search']) }}
          <!--   {!! Html::image('blog/images/search_btn.gif', 'alt', array( 'class' => 'button_search' )) !!} 
           {{ Form::image('blog/images/search_btn.gif', 'button_search', ['class' => 'button_search]) }}
          <input name="button_search" src="images/search_btn.gif" class="button_search" type="image" />-->

          <span>
          <input name="editbox_search" class="editbox_search" id="editbox_search" maxlength="80" value="Search" type="text" />
          </span>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="clr"></div>
      <div class="logo">
        <h1><a href="index.html">EnergyBox<br />
          <small>put your slogan here</small></a></h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  @yield('content')
  </div>
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer_resize">
      <p class="lf">&copy; Copyright MyWebSite. Designed by Blue <a href="http://www.bluewebtemplates.com/">Website Templates</a></p>
      <ul class="fmenu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="support.html">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clr"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div align=center>This template  downloaded form <a href='http://all-free-download.com/free-website-templates/'>free website templates</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing `'` on line 31:

```
{{ Form::image('blog/images/search_btn.gif', 'button_search', ['class' => 'button_search]) }}
```

Should be:

```
{{ Form::image('blog/images/search_btn.gif', 'button_search', ['class' => 'button_search']) }}
```

Also if you're working with Blade, use Blade's comment syntax instead of HTML's:

```
<!-- This is a HTML comment -->

{{-- This is a Blade comment, any blade code within this comment won't be parsed. --}}
```

Comment: Thanks bro.got it! :)
My mistake was putting wrong comment tag